# gitlab access over ssh

Tags: git, gitlab

I am just wondering if there is an access to gitlab repositories over ssh ?

As I see on my installation gitlab offers only two kinds of links to repositories: http and git.  But, as I know the git protocol does not have authentication.

Comment: What do you mean git protocol doesn't have authentication..? Have you tried to access your repos over ssh (git@...) ?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html - "provides a service similar to the SSH protocol, but with absolutely no authentication"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GitLab authentication should offer https and ssh for accessing the git repos.

```
git@server:repo.git
```

The url above *is* an ssh url, accessing the server as user `git`.

And the installation should take place with an account like '`git`', which should be the only one accessing the GitLab server (as executing directly commands through an interactive shell).
All other users don't have direct access, and are only registered as GitLab users in the GitLab database.

Comment: Hmm... May be I something missing, but look at this screenshot http://blog.gitlab.org/images/screens/gitlab_project.png.  Here is a SSH button, to get URL to repository, but links starts with git@, not ssh@.

Comment: That _is_ access over ssh. Ssh@ would be access over ssh as a user named ssh.

Comment: @demas I second what AD7six wrote. I have edited the answer to make clear what an ssh url is.

Comment: Thanks.  What port do I need to open when I will clone such repository: ssh (22) or git (9418) ?

Comment: @demas ssh 22. 9418 has nothing to do with ssh, and everything with git protocol used by a git daemon (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon), and not useful in your case since it doesn't offer any authentication (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon). See all protocols at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols