# Cloning repo through GitLab using ssh key

Tags: linux, git, networking, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to clone a private repo through GitLab over ssh .I have already generated ssh key and fed the same in my profile. I am successfully able to run **ssh -T git@gitlab.com**.But while cloning I am getting error like **remote: ERROR: Git access over SSH is not allowed**>.
Please let me know if I am missing anything, any permissions I have to give for the repository to clone through ssh.I am able to do through https.

Comment: Verify that the SSH key you've added to your GitLab profile is the correct one and matches the private key stored on your local machine.

Comment: What is the exact command you ran? Is there anything else in the error message?

Comment: @sneha I have added public key on GIT lab rather than private key. Is that correct ?

Comment: No only this was the only error i am getting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776921/gitlab-access-over-ssh check if this helps.

Comment: Yes. You should add the public key to GitLab, not the private key. Public key is used by GitLab to authenticate you. The private key should remain on your local machine and should not be shared or added to GitLab.